# How Can I Make Configurations for MySQL to Log Only Important Things Like "Error"

Tags: 18.04, server, mysql, log, mariadb

A MariaDB-Mysql server is logging everything and somethimes logs reach 100gb+ and they grows until the logrotate rotates them. I want that the MySQL must only logs necessary things like Error, not Warn or Info (or something like this I don't know very well the Mysql logging strategies). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a primary server that is replicating data to other systems, the logs can certainly grow to be quite large very quickly. Informational messages cannot be suppressed as far as I know, but you can shut off the warning messages like this:

1. Connect to the database as `root` or a user that has admin privileges
2. Disable the warning logging: `SET GLOBAL log_warnings=0;`
3. Monitor your logs

If this gives you exactly what you want, then you'll need to update your `my.cnf` file to add `log_warnings=0;` somewhere so that the setting persists across restarts.

If you want to reduce *all* logging as much as possible, then you'll want to see what is writing to the various log files:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%';
```

This will give you something that looks like:

```
+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                        |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| back_log                        | 50                           | 
| binlog_cache_size               | 65535                        | 
| expire_logs_days                | 0                            | 
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 1                            | 
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                          | 
| innodb_log_arch_dir             |                              | 
| innodb_log_archive              | OFF                          | 
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 1048576                      | 
| innodb_log_file_size            | 5242880                      | 
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                            | 
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       | ./                           | 
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                            | 
| log                             | ON                           | 
| log_bin                         | ON                           | 
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                          | 
| log_error                       | /logs/mysql/mysqld.error.log | 
| log_queries_not_using_indexes   | OFF                          | 
| log_slave_updates               | OFF                          | 
| log_slow_queries                | ON                           | 
| log_warnings                    | 1                            | 
| max_binlog_cache_size           | 4294967295                   | 
| max_binlog_size                 | 1073741824                   | 
| max_relay_log_size              | 0                            | 
| relay_log_purge                 | ON                           | 
| relay_log_space_limit           | 0                            | 
| sync_binlog                     | 0                            | 
+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See what's `ON` and, if it's not required, use `SET GLOBAL` to change the values to `OFF`. Remember that anything you do with `SET GLOBAL` will not persist across restarts, so you can *test* with `SET GLOBAL`, then make the changes permanent by writing the value to the appropriate configuration file.

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: log_warnings in my.cnf file was like that "log_warnings = 2". I updated it as 0. Will it logs errors?

Comment: Errors are separate from warnings. Yes, your log will continue to receive errors so long as you have not disabled logging completely.